# Python TypeError str object is not callable inside a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I am trying to convert a string into a list in the loop, it works for the first instace and it works without a loop. But i am getting the error while placing it inside a loop. This is how my code looks as of now
And my error is

*line 49, in 
mi.append("") if(pd.isnull(i)) else mi.append(str(i))*
**TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

```
mi=[]
ni=[] 
for col in df.columns:
  # for ind in df.index:
    # print(df[j][i])
    zxt=df[col].tolist()
    

    for i in zxt:
      
        mi.append("") if(pd.isnull(i)) else mi.append(str(i))
    row3=""
    row2=""

    count=0
    str=""
    # print(mi)
    print("For Column",col)
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    def remove(x, replacer):
        global count
        count2=0
        for i in x:
            if f"'{i}'" == ascii(i):
                pass
            else:
                count=count+1
                print("flag hit")
                TestText2 = x.encode('utf8')
                print(TestText2,"\n")
                x=x.replace(i,replacer)
                
        return x
    for row in mi:
      remove(row,'')
      ni.append(row)

    print("characters out of order for",count,"times")
    mi.clear()
```

Comment: Why not just post the traceback message in a code block?

Comment: `str=""` - you've shadowed the builtin `str` function with a like-named variable assigned to a string. So, `str(i)` is `""(i)`. You should use a different name for that variable.

Comment: THIS IS MY ENTIRE TRACEBACK MESSAGE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xya\Documents\xys\xyz\experiment.py", line 49, in <module>
    mi.append("") if(pd.isnull(i)) else mi.append(str(i))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @tdelaney , the str was the one casuing the problems. Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in zxt:
   if pd.isnull(i):
        mi.append("")    
   else:
        mi.append(str(i))
```

Unless you've copied your code incorrectly in the question?

Comment: But that's the same thing as the ternary operator already used.

Comment: I already used the same thing as a ternary operator. Plus its working if i run it as a single element and not in loop